# ASP.NET Web Application Core - How to manipulate data in AspNetUsers to different tables based on roles?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, .net-core

I do not know how to properly phrase the question, but I'll try my best. I am implementing role-based authorization in my web application. Identity in ASP.NET stores accounts into AspNetUsers, but I am tasked to separate all accounts of Role A to be stored in a new table, and all accounts of Role B to be stored in another table. Is there any way that this can be achieved? I am also not experienced in ASP.NET so I may need help understanding this.

Comment: _"I am tasked to separate all accounts of Role A to be stored in a new table, and all accounts of Role B to be stored in another table"_ ...before we start, step back and ask ... **why**? What benefit will that bring? This sounds suspiciously like denormalising the data, and also why mess with something which already works as designed? I smell an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: i would ask who ever is asking for these requirement more questions.... before coming here.. your "problem" is not design or code, its why are we doing what is being asked.... and if you are then they should explain why.

Comment: I have been tasked by my lecturer (who does not have much knowledge on this topic) to separate accounts by role to prevent the mixing of data. The roles are Administrator and Users I am not able to make a convincing argument to change his mind about this separation, and he is pretty stubborn when it comes to hearing other people's ideas...

Comment: You're absolutely right, your lecturer doesn't know much! And sounds like they lack a lot of understanding of relational databases. It's unclear what "mixing" they are talking about. The way you prevent getting the wrong results in a database is by writing the queries correctly. Where you store the data doesn't matter from that perspective, the important thing is that the data is correctly normalised so it can be queried easily and correctly. This request is completely illogical. It's also not likely to work properly because you would also need to change Microsoft's code to support it.

Comment: Haha, I'll try my absolute best to convince him again. How do you think I can approach this in a simple way such that this idea gets into his head?

Comment: Tricky because I don't understand what his exact level is. But if you are confident explaining database normalisation, you should point out that the most basic rule of normalised data is that you don't store the same kinds of data in separate tables. So if you have "users", they always will belong together in one table, because they have the same properties in common. If they are in a different role, that can be represented by a property in the table, or by a secondary table (for many-to-many relationships).

Comment: Also it's definitely worth pointing out that changing the data structure will inevitably mean that the ASP.NET Identity code would need to be modified to know how to get the data from the different structure. But that's not your code and, while it may be open-source, modifying it would inevitably mean it falls out of line with Microsoft, so it would be impossible to get help from them or the community if there were issues, and updates from MS would be incompatible....

Comment: ...MS have the experts on this stuff, they designed something which works correctly and in an industry-standard way. So it makes no sense to mess with it at all. Especially when it's something sensitive like login / security - mistakes could easily lead to vulnerabilities in the code which mean the process is no longer properly secure. I cannot see any real tangible benefit from modifying this table structure. All it will do is create problems instead of solving them.

Comment: The "mixing of data" thing appears to be a non-problem stemming from some sort of misunderstanding about how databases are supposed to work. So another thing you could do is to challenge your lecturer to give a clear, worked-through example showing what exact problem he thinks could occur because of the current structure, and demonstrating how to cause it and/or exploit it. I would be willing to bet it will either not be demonstratable, or will be based on some spurious assumptions.

Comment: (N.B. I suppose it's possible that this whole exercise is intended to be a trick question and your lecturer is deliberately winding you up, and is actually hoping you'll all come back saying "this is a terrible idea, don't do it, here's why...". It would be nice if that was the case, but your comments on your lecturer's level of knowledge suggest that this may not be the case unfortunately. The last thing you could do of course is show him this question, if you dare. And give him some links to some database design tutorials.)

Comment: I really appreciate you taking your time to write this! I'll definitely *try* to convey this information to him and see how it goes. Wish me luck... :c

Comment: Absolutely - best of luck! And sorry that you seem to be stuck with some rather poor-quality teaching. Hopefully the vast resources of today's web can make up for it somewhat. When I was studying, there was nowhere near the amount of material online and it was harder to access - you were mostly stuck with the course textbooks and anything you could get from the uni library (which was mostly academic rather than practical). As a group of students we relied quite a bit on teaching each other - often one person would "get" a concept before everyone else and then be able to help them out with it.